# Can container (not container-fluid) be 100% wide when viewport is < XXXpx with Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, breakpoints

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and noticing that I'm losing precious horizontal real estate at every breakpoint. I'd like for the outermost container to be 100% wide any time  the browser is < 1200px.

I added this to my CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  body > .container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1140px;
  } 
}
```

I used 1140px as the width because that's what the documentation said the max width of an element with `.contianer` can be.

You can see it [here](https://codepen.io/daveh0/pen/gZyywj).

When I resize the browser, everything adjusts as I intended, but is this just a case of getting lucky and that changing the width from Bootstrap's core values totally jacks up the grid? Is here a "correct" way to do this using `.container-fluid`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the exact solution of your question: https://www.beyondjava.net/how-to-add-a-new-breakpoint-in-bootstrap

When you are using Bootstrap 4, you should use it's basic features like `media-breakpoints`.

In the **bootstrap_config** and **_variables** you can specify the point of each breakpoint at how wide the screen should be to trigger it.

**NOTE: in this case, the `lg` stands for your own choise wich breakpoint you want to give the value 1200px**

In this case if you config your boostrap to trigger the `lg` classes at `1200px`, then if you add the following code, on every screen which is less wide than `1200px`, the container class will be `100%` in width.

```
@include media-breakpoint-down(lg){
    .container{
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1140px;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you might want to point out that you have to modify the source sass files.

Comment: Yes, you have to modify the bootstrap_config and _variables files and also linked a helper article how to do it

Answer (score 0):

So you basically want your container to behave the same way as `.container-fluid` when your viewport is less than 1200px. I think [Patrik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54246779/2518200) is the most correct way to do this (by modifying the source file), but if you don't want to do that, then I think your method is OK.

However, I think the CSS you are using in your ruleset could be revised. You could set the `max-width` property to `none` which is the default value for that property. This has the effect of unsetting whatever Bootstrap's CSS applies for this property.

```
@media (max-width: 1199px) {
    body > .container {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: none;
    } 
}
```

MDN article showing `none` as the default value for `max-width`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width#Values

Comment: in Bootstrap 4  `.container` has a `max-width` property, so it needs to stay, otherwise it jumps to 1140, 960, 720 or 540 rather than 100%.

Comment: @Daveh0 oh yes, you are right, sorry. Maybe it would be best to set it to `none` which is the default value. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Daveh0 That should unset whatever Bootstrap applies. And now that I think about it `.container` already applies those margins and paddings, so you don't need that stuff.

Comment: Yup, that's what I just ended up with as well. In the end, I'll probably use Patrik's solution above, but this will definitely suffice for my prototyping needs. Thanks.